# Event Names not showing up on Etherscan

Tags: events, etherscan

For some reason Event Names associated with transactions to my contracts aren't being shown in their [Event Logs](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x6c9b10b158e76a61c24bec305d5be60de1c25997#events) on Etherscan. Worth noting, this event in particular is not indexed.

Any thoughts as to why they aren't displaying like they are for this [transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x88ceb0dca6d9ad1007e534712ae4e67565d9e1a56244cf32a463dc9dd5f7ef4f#eventlog)?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [verify and publish](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x6c9b10b158e76a61c24bec305d5be60de1c25997) your smart contract code in order for Etherscan to pick up the event names.